# Raspbian Jessie boot recovery

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I updated an older Raspbian Jessie image (imaged around April/May of 2016) using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y`, followed by an `sudo rpi-update` straight after. This is on an RPi 2 B. A reboot resulted in a quickly flashing boot screen with 4 Raspberries, followed by a reboot, ad infinitum.

Is there any way I can get this image back to working order, without starting over? I've looked in `/boot' but cannot see older kernel images or anything I can switch to. Any other tips on where I should look to find the fault in the boot sequence (e.g. a log file or something) would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Comment: ouch. I thought I needed that to get a pre-3B firmware upgraded to a 3B firmware. This SD card needs to work in both 2Bs as well as 3Bs, hence why.

Comment: Well, it wasn't rpi-update. Was able to get into the same infinite boot loop with another image that hadn't had a update && dist-upgrade in a few months. Guess I'll have to start fresh and reconfigure my image. I tried copying /boot and /lib/modules /lib/modprobe.d over from a working Jessie to the bricked one but that didn't help.